# Tor browser on Ubuntu 23.10, Rpi5?

Tags: raspberrypi, 23.10

Is there anyone in here who has any luck making Tor Browser working on Ubuntu ? It works out of the box with Raspberry pi OS using pi-apps. But on Ubuntu I don't get further than: **Gah. Your tab just crashed.** :-)

To me, the logging suggests it's a graphics issue:

```
Fontconfig warning: "/home/---/tor-browser/Browser/fontconfig/fonts.conf", line 42: Use of ambiguous path in <dir> element. please add prefix="cwd" if current behavior is desired.
Fontconfig warning: "/home/---/tor-browser/Browser/fontconfig/fonts.conf", line 118: unknown element "blank"
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: glxtest: DRM device has no render node (t=1.75423) [GFX1-]: glxtest: DRM device has no render node
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: glxtest: DRM device has no render node (t=1.75423) |[1][GFX1-]: No GPUs detected via PCI (t=1.75432) [GFX1-]: No GPUs detected via PCI
Fontconfig warning: "/home/---/tor-browser/Browser/fontconfig/fonts.conf", line 42: Use of ambiguous path in <dir> element. please add prefix="cwd" if current behavior is desired.
Fontconfig warning: "/home/---/tor-browser/Browser/fontconfig/fonts.conf", line 118: unknown element "blank"
Fontconfig warning: "/home/---/tor-browser/Browser/fontconfig/fonts.conf", line 42: Use of ambiguous path in <dir> element. please add prefix="cwd" if current behavior is desired.
Fontconfig warning: "/home/---/tor-browser/Browser/fontconfig/fonts.conf", line 118: unknown element "blank"
```

But whatever it is, it doesn't help disabling all hardware acceleration features. Not in the Settings nor in about:config.

Or maybe this is something else entirely...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the arm64 version from https://sourceforge.net/projects/tor-browser-ports/.